# Why number of Threads is more than 1 in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am working on Parallel processing project. One of the tasks is getting the number of threads for the current running process.

I am using this method:

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            label1.Text = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count.ToString();
  }
```

But it gives me a very strange result, which is **(13) !!**, however I have only one thread which is the UIThread and it should be **(1)** and I have not created any extra threads yet..

Can anyone explain that result for me?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yunjin/2005/07/05/special-threads-in-clr/

Comment: The operating system and the .NET Framework like to use threads as well.  Enable unmanaged debugging and use the Debug > Windows > Threads window to have a look-see.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks @YacoubMassad, this link has the information that I was looking for..

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for the answer, it gives more details about the threads.. 
Is there any way to get the number of threads that I create by using codes like Thread t=new Thread()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every .NET application creates and maintains Thread Pool by default. You can limit it's size via [ThreadPool.SetMaxThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but you must understand consequences of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. but is there any way to count the threads that I create by myself for example using Thread thread=new Thread().. something like this??

Comment: Can you explain little bit your concern with the number of threads? I guess there may be a better approach since there are (big) chances you are taking free threads from the thread pool, not creating them.

Comment: Let me explain more: in fact my project is about distributed computing and parallel processing. I have a big task and I want to create a number processes first, and distribute these processes over the computers. 
Then I want to create multi-threads for each process to execute the task to reduce (CPU execution time).
**my question:** is there any way to get the exact number of the threads That I created to execute the tasks and still running, not the ones form the pool?? for example I create 3 threads I want to get 3 by calling a method.

Comment: You have multiple options, one of them is to enumerate every thread and check it's `IsThreadPoolThread` property. Have you seen existing open-source distributed solutions out there such as Microsoft Orleans, Akka.NET etc? Rolling your own distributed solution without understanding of `Thread` and `Task` concepts looks more like yak shaving, to be fair

Comment: Thank You, I got the solution.. I created an arraylist of my own threads, then I give name for each of them, then by the name I can recognize each of my threads. I use thread.name="something" and therad.isAlive to check if the thread still running or not..
about the excising similes software, It is a research of one of my friends and I am helping in programming.. now, I am in process of understanding the detailed concepts :)
thanks again,, your words helped me too much