# Is there a way to get number of threads that I create in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am working on a parallel processing project, I am creating some threads to run multiple tasks.. 
For example:

```
Thread t1=new Thread(...);
Thread t2=new Thread(...);
Thread t3=new Thread(...);
```

Now, I want to get the number of running threads in this process. I use the following code for that:

```
label1.Text = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count.ToString();
```

it gives me **13**, I got the answer from this link why it returns 13 from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36477357/2202452):

**My question:** Is there a way to get number of these threads that I created in this process and still running? I expect to get **3** as I only created 3 threads and they are running.

Comment: Why not count them yourself? There's nothing that differentiates *your* creation of a thread from the framework creating one - and even more importantly, a third party library creating a thread (since it's also user code).

Comment: Why not just keep a list of threads you created?

Comment: Thanks for answers guys,, I want to count the living ones,, is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add / remove your threads to a `List<Thread>` as you start / stop them.  You will be able to query this list for any information you need about your threads.  This will only be accurate for *your* threads though, as .NET will create a few of its own threads for garbage collection and use in the Thread Pool.

Comment: Thanks Bradley,, Yeah I created a list of the threads and I give the threads names.. by using the following commands: **thread.name="something"** it is for recognizing the threads,, and **thread.isAlive** is for knowing if the thread is still running or not.